# Eta-expansion on non-methods works for fields but not for local variables

Tags: scala

The following code is pretty much self-explanatory:

```
class EtaExpansionOnNonMethods { // or object
    val zero = 0
    val zeroEta = zero _ // compiles: () => Int

    def f {
        val one = 1
        val oneEta = one _ // compilation error
    }
}
```

```
Error:(7, 18) _ must follow method; cannot follow Int
    val oneEta = one _
                 ^
```

Why is eta-expansion on an e.g. `Int` field allowed (resulting in `() => Int`) but not on an `Int` local variable (resulting in a compilation error)? I'm using version 2.11.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `val` members are actually compiled down to getter/setter-like methods, for example running `javap EtaExpansionOnNonMethods.class` that you'd get from running `scalac` gives you:

```
E:\EtaExp>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\javap" EtaExpansionOnNonMethods.class
Compiled from "EtaExp.scala"
public class EtaExpansionOnNonMethods {
  public int zero();
  public EtaExpansionOnNonMethods();
}
```

Notice that if you were to declare the member as `private[this] val zero = 0`, which is compiled down to a final field, you'd get the exact same error you get when trying to eta-expand a local variable or value.

In the end, the general premise still holds: you can use eta-expansion on methods, even when those methods are not really explicit. :)

Comment: Can you direct me to the section in the SLS where this behavior is defined?

Comment: @xehpuk Honestly, I can't find anything in the spec saying how the `val`s should compile, so I'm not sure whether it's documented somewhere (and I just can't find it right now), or if it's an implementation detail.